# SQL Select Issue: How to split Column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working in SQL Server 2012 (Express Edition). I have one table named as Observations. In that table I have 2 columns "Observations, ObservationType". There are only two types of observations in the table:

1. Clinical
2. Non-Clinical

My table structure look like this..

```
Observations     ObservationType
-------------------------------
AAAA            Clinical
BBBB            Clincal
CCCC            Non-Clinical
DDDD            Clinical
EEEE            Non-Clinical
```

Now I have to select all row explicitly based on observation type
I tried but my output was like

```
Clinical                 Non-Clinical
---------------------------------------
AAAA                        NULL
BBBB                        NULL
NULL                        CCCC
DDDD                        NULL
NULL                        EEEE
```

But I want like this

```
Clinical                 Non-Clinical
---------------------------------------
AAAA                        CCCC
BBBB                        EEEE
DDDD
```

Comment: I would suggest against that dataset, if I am honest. *Why* do you want to data like that?

Comment: @Larnu  I want to export the data in that format as per client's requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, because the columns in a row have nothing to do with each other.  However, you can accomplish this by using `row_number()` to generate a sequence number and then aggregate:

```
select max(case when ObservationType = 'Clinical' then Observation end) as Clinical,
       max(case when ObservationType = 'Non-Clinical' then Observation end) as NonClinical
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ObservationType order by Observation) as seqnum
      from Observations o
     ) o
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: ! It works! Thank you. Can you please just explain a little more that how the thing is going on? (if you don't mind)